# GParted: Cannot expand the partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I am not able to expand my Ubuntu partition even though I have unalloacted space adjacent to it. Can someone help me please?

[image: Gparted Partitioning Image]

Comment: It's space *after* what you need, not just adjacent. You need to move it to the left first.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding a partition+filesystem to the left is a relatively complex operation that cannot be performed when the filesystem is mounted. You need to `umount` first. If you wanted to shrink the filesystem, the problem would be the same. Some filesystems support expanding to the right while mounted.

GParted shows you the icon of a key in the *Partition* column to indicate you cannot easily modify the partition+filesystem.

In some cases you may be able to `umount` and proceed; especially if the filesystem is not crucial to the running OS.

The filesystem in question is mounted as `/`. It's most crucial. You cannot `umount` it now because the majority of your (currently running) OS lives there.

Solution: boot Linux from live CD, pendrive or whatever, so the filesystem you want to alter is not mounted at all; then act. Expanding to the left is not trivial, it's advised to backup the data first.