# Extending Ubuntu system partition by space before it

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, filesystems, gparted, dualboot

Sorry, there was similar question before, but still can not find satisfactory answer.
Is there any ways to extend Ubuntu partition with the free space before it without deleting and recreating partition and reinstalling OS? Maybe, there are some useful apps for Windows? AOMEI, for example?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O485Z.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1441475/432690).

Comment: Thank you very much. So, if I would be able to extend this partition from Windows PE using AOMEI (it seems to have this feature) will it be still bootable? Is it enough just to move files to the beginning of this space to preserve startup ability? I hope so)

Comment: To reiterate the statement by @KamilMaciorowski : make a complete disk image, whether with *dd* or a third party tool (even free Windows tool Macrium Reflect, run from USB), *before attempting to make any change*. That image can also be used to restore to a *larger* partition.

Comment: I know neither Windows nor AOMEI. The linked answer is the best what I can tell you, nothing more.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: In a nutshell, you must understand that any partition management comes with the risk of data loss, hence the need for backups as commented above. Expanding ("to the right") a partition has a very low risk and is fast because we're changing the end point only, no data needs to be touched, whereas when moving then expanding everything inside must be moved as well so the risk is much higher -and- it takes a lot more time to finish the operation. NB - Use a **live session** for that. Conversely use Windows tools to manage Windows partitions (NTFS, etc.)

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yes, I understand the risk but if everything will be executed properly it does not affect loading ability of Windows and Ubuntu, does it?

Comment: The risk exists even when doing everything correctly, hence the need for good backups.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved. I have booted from installation Ubuntu USB and started the Try Ubuntu mode. Then I used Gparted to extend the partition to the left. Everything completed successfully. Both Windows and Ubuntu are bootable.
Hope my answer will help someone else.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.